# Ubuntu reinstallation - boot loader device (not UEFI)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, system-installation

I have problems with my current Ubuntu installation, and am about to reinstall.  My current configuration is as below:

[image: Partitions]

Since I'm not sure where the problem lies, I am going to format both Ubuntu partitions with the same configuration (sda4 mounted as / and sda5 mounted as /home) which is easy enough.

My question is, for 'Device for boot loader installation' am I correct in selecting /dev/sda? I assume that this is the current boot loader location and that grub will then read sda1 for W10 loader?

Note that I am not using UEFI.

I don't want to mess up my W10 loader or any other W10 partitions.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you're correct about the device for bootloader and you can reuse the partitions. Just select "something else..." during the installation and proceed accordingly.

Comment: You do have to be careful as grub only boots working Windows. And hibernated or needing chkdsk is not working. So best to have a Windows repair/recovery disk with repair console, or know how to temporarily install a Windows type boot loader syslinux or lilo to MBR to directly boot Windows to get into internal  repair console.  Windows 8 or 10's always on hibernation or fast start up may get turned back on with updates or anytime you have corruption, you may need chkdsk.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Copy-paste the text and add four spaces at the start of each line for preformatted text. Click the "edit" button underneath your post if you want to change it now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, /dev/sda is correct. Grub will handle passing control to the Windows bootloader. I have seen extra windows partitions, but never a specific windows bootloader partition except in UEFI EFI partitions. I may have just not noticed since I don't use the Windows partition much.